# Solving a cubic equation using pure python NO NUMPY or SCIPY

Tags: python, math, calculus

I was wondering if I could get help solving a generic cubic polynomial with coefficients a, b, c and d. I don't want to use scipy or numpy.

For any complex-valued parameters, I want to find all 3 roots of the equation.

This is what i attempted so far,

```
def cubic_formula(a,b,c,d):
if not a==0:
    x=-(b**3)/(27*(a**3))+(b*c)/(6*(a**2))-d/(2*a)
    y=x**2+(c/(3*a)-b/(9*(a**2)))**3
    return ((x-(y**(1/2)))**(1/3))+((x+(y**(1/2)))-b/(3*a)**(1/3)
elif not b==0:
    br=c**2-4*b*d
    rt=(-c+(br**(1/2)))/(2*b),(-c-(br**(1/2)))/(2*b)
    return rt if not br==0 else -c/(2*b)
elif not c==0:
    return -d/c
else:
        if d==0:
```

How do I simplify my solution if d = 0? and how do I retrieve all the results as length-3 (or less if the solutions are fewer) tuple of numbers?

I know x = 0 is a solution that can be taken out x(a^2 + bx + c) = 0, which wields a normal quadratic function and another root at x = 0, however, I don't know how to code it in python and print out the answer.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

Only thing wrong with my code was that

```
if not a==0:
    x=-(b**3)/(27*(a**3))+(b*c)/(6*(a**2))-d/(2*a)
    y=x**2+c/(3*a)-b/(9*(a**2)))**3
    return ((x-(y**(1/2)))**(1/3))++(x+(y**(1/2)))-b/(3*a)**(1/3)
```

only returned 1 value instead of 3 :) Nothing to do with

```
else
   if d=0
```

Comment: you may be very interested in Sympy, which is a symbolic solver and can lambdify the resulting expression to various backends https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/utilities/lambdify.html

Comment: @ti7 thank you for your response, but I want to learn how to write it in pure python hahaha without using packages or anything.

Comment: You should never use 1/3 for your exponents.  You should understand that integer division is different.  1/3 = 0; 1./3. = 0.33333333.....  A cubic equation always has three roots.  You should always return three.

Comment: How do I find the cube root of something if I can’t use 1/3 as an exponent using pure python

Answer (score 0):

When `d = 0`, `ax³ + b x² + c x + d = 0` degenerates to `x = 0` and the quadratic `ax² + bx + c = 0`.

In all cases, you can return the results as a list or a tuple (possibly empty). E.g. `return (a+b, a-b)`.

Comment: haha yes, I get that, You can sub out the x in the equation and then receives a quadratic, then you can use the quadratic formula to return both complex and real numbers, however I'm struggling to write this in python as I'm really struggling and brand new to coding.

Comment: @Intel4004: and ? So far you programmed more difficult than the quadratic so what do you mean ?

Comment: Yep, but how do i return every solution into the equation ?

Comment: except if you knew what my code was, the d = 0 did not provide anything as the function defined in my code was if not a = 0 and then elif not b = 0 and so on means that if a, b, c and d were all 0. Which in fact the entire part I edited, which you claimed is ‘helping me’, is wrong and my code was already completed. Just that the ‘if not a = 0’ did not print the complex values and only one value I.e the real root instead of the 3 values

Comment: @Intel4004: no problem, keep disregarding my answer.

Comment: Your answer isn't disregarded, it was just wrong to begin with.

Your second part was only the one partially correct but your first sentence was completely wrong.

Comment: @Intel4004: in what way is the first sentence wrong ?

Comment: in terms of pure mathematics, your first sentence is correct. However, in my code, it didn't ask about factorising when JUST d = 0, as it would've been no solution. When a = b = c = d = 0, there is no solution

if not a == 0, gave a cubic, elif not b == 0 gave a quadratic, elif c == 0 gave a linear equation, else d = 0 would've provided no solution

Comment: @Intel4004: well "your first sentence is correct" does not match "it was just wrong to begin with", nor "your first sentence was completely wrong". And unless I have been hacked, I read "How do I simplify my solution if d = 0? " and my first sentence addresses exactly that. Furthermore, there is no mention of the case a = b = c = d = 0 anywhere and in such a case all x are solutions. So I guess you are just trolling me.

Comment: do you not realise that in the code above, if a = 0, it then moves to the next part and if b also = 0, it moves to the next part ? lol, if I wrote ```print(cubic_equation(1,0,0,0)```, the code will still return in the part where it says ```if not a == 0```. ```((x-(y**(1/2)))**(1/3))+((x+(y**(1/2)))-b/(3*a)**(1/3)```. Only when a = 0, the code will move to ```elif not b ==0```. and same with ```elif not b==0:```, if i wrote ```print(cubic_equation(0,1,0,0)```. It will still return this set of code ```return rt if not br==0 else -c/(2*b)``` and continuing, ```else if d = 0``` will only be used

Comment: when ```print(cubic_equation(0,0,0,0)``` is used